# setResultState in React component is not defined

Tags: reactjs

I have an example created using a functional component in React that fetches some data, processes it and feeds it to a grid component that displays it, and collapses some groups, code and example can be found here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/kendo-react-jsonplaceholder-rg6rpt?file=app/main.jsx

It works but I want to rewrite it to a Class component and currently by data fetching does not work, I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: setResultState is not defined
```

I am not sure how to implement the Hooks logic with `setResultState` to my Class component. What is the correct way to do it? Here is my example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/kendo-react-jsonplaceholder-vkf341?file=app/main.jsx

and my code:

```
const initialDataState = {
  take: 10,
  skip: 0,
  products: [],
  group: [
    {
      field: 'id',
    },
  ],
};

const processWithGroups = (data, dataState) => {
  const newDataState = process(data, dataState);
  setGroupIds({
    data: newDataState.data,
    group: dataState.group,
  });
  return newDataState;
};

const onExpandChange = () => {
  useMemo(() => (event) => {
    const newDataState = processWithGroups(products, event.dataState);
    setDataState(event.dataState);
    setResultState(newDataState);
  });
};

const onDataStateChange = () => {
  useMemo(() => {
    (event) => {
      const newDataState = processWithGroups(products, event.dataState);
      setDataState(event.dataState);
      setResultState(newDataState);
    },
      [products];
  });
};

class App extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    dataState: initialDataState,
    result: processWithGroups(initialDataState.products, initialDataState),
    collapsedState: [],
    resultState: processWithGroups(initialDataState.products, initialDataState),
  };
  dataStateChange = (event) => {
    const newDataState = processWithGroups(
      this.state.products,
      event.dataState
    );
    this.setState({
      result: newDataState,
      dataState: event.dataState,
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(
      'https://otp.metroservices.io/otp/routers/default/index/routes/uscalacmtarail:801/stops'
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        const newDataState = processWithGroups(json, this.state.dataState);
        setResultState(newDataState);
        setProducts(json);
        console.log(response);
      });
  }

  expandChange = (event) => {
    const item = event.dataItem;

    if (item.groupId) {
      const newCollapsedIds = !event.value
        ? [...this.state.collapsedState, item.groupId]
        : this.state.collapsedState.filter(
            (groupId) => groupId !== item.groupId
          );
      this.setState({
        collapsedIds: newCollapsedIds,
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const newData = setExpandedState({
      data: this.state.result.data,
      collapsedIds: this.state.collapsedState,
    });
    return (
      <Grid
        style={{
          height: '520px',
        }}
        pageable={{
          pageSizes: true,
        }}
        groupable={true}
        data={newData}
        total={this.state.resultState.total}
        onDataStateChange={onDataStateChange}
        {...this.state.dataState}
        onExpandChange={onExpandChange}
        expandField="expanded"
      >
        <Column field="id" filterable={false} title="ID" width="50px" />
        <Column field="name" title="Name" />
        <Column field="cluster" title="Cluster" />
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('my-app'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that problem is in line

```
result: processWithGroups(this.state.products, initialDataState),
```

where you are trying to read state which is not set yet